# Electron + React Proxy Port for API

Tags: reactjs, proxy, electron, axios

I'm building an electron wrapped react app. Generally, using `create-react-app`, I can specify a `proxy` in the `package.json` so that axios knows to use a different PORT during development. However, I think the electron piece is doing some overriding because even though react runs on 3000 by default, all my axios requests are routed to `:5000` which is the electron port. Anyone know how to get axios to use a different port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a custom instance of axios and use it instead.

*axiosConfig.js*

```
const customAxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:5000',
});
```

*The below code comes where you call the endpoint of the API*

```
import APIEndPoint from './axiosConfig';

APIEndPoint
  .get('/your-end-points-here')
  .then((response) => {
    // handle success
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle error
  })
})
```

Comment: I kind had that. Was missing a part. I think that will work for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though not an answer to your question but if your intent is communicating between react-app and electron then I would suggest using IPC(ipcMain & ipcRenderer) calls to communicate between your react-app and electron. Please refer to the below links.

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

Comment: My intent is communicating to an API. I really just need the react portion to hit that API.